# Something wrong with execute in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I make function that will change type of columns of any table. And for example I create a table test:

```
create table test(id text, name text, born text);
```

```
insert into test values ('1', 'Ivanov', '10-10-2012'), ('2', 'Petrov', '01-01-1999'),
 ('3', 'Sidorov', '03-12-1975');
```

And then make table with column name and new data type:

```
create table col_types(column_name text, data_type text);
```

```
insert into col_types values ('id', 'integer'), ('name', 'text'),
 ('born', 'date');
```

This my function:

```
create or replace function change_columns(my_table text, columns_types_table text) returns void as $$
    declare
        r text;
        cur_type text;
    begin
        raise notice 'NOTICE smth: %', 1;
        for r in (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = my_table) loop
            raise notice 'NOTICE r: %', 2;
            execute 'select data_type from ' -- ERROR here
                        || quote_ident(columns_types_table)
                        || ' where column_name = '
                        || quote_ident(r)
            into strict cur_type;
            raise notice 'NOTICE cur_type: %', 3;
            execute 'alter table ' 
                        || quote_ident(my_table) 
                        || ' alter column '
                        || quote_ident(r)
                        ||' type '
                        || quote_ident(cur_type)
                        || ' using ' 
                        || r 
                        || '::' 
                        || cur_type;
        end loop;
    end
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

My ERROR:

```
ERROR: column "id" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function change_columns(text,text) line 9 at EXECUTE
```

Function request:

```
select change_columns('test', 'col_types');
```

Answer (score 2):

The [full error message](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=69e544f0321d440c71681e23fc571d80) (at least in Postgres 14) is

```
ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: select data_type from col_types where column_name = id
                                                            ^
QUERY:  select data_type from col_types where column_name = id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function change_columns(text,text) line 9 at EXECUTE
```

which makes it easy to see where you went wrong: `id` is treated as an identifier here. You actually wanted to run the query

```
select data_type from col_types where column_name = 'id'
--                                                  ^  ^
```

To generate this, you need to use `quote_literal` instead of `quote_identifier`:

```
execute 'select data_type from '
     || quote_ident(columns_types_table)
     || ' where column_name = '
     || quote_literal(r)
into strict cur_type;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5c4ddca40e895749ea160bf23bb4353a). Notice I also had to change the `alter column` statement not to escape the type name)</sup>

An even better approach would be to use a [parameterised query with a `USING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
execute 'select data_type from '
     || quote_ident(columns_types_table)
     || ' where column_name = $1'
into strict cur_type
using r;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=07fd59fcf0f3cb9d2715b30820fdb3c5))</sup>